# how to apply text classification using Graph2Vec embeddings?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, text-classification, embedding

I got a collection of text documents, separated on directories based on the subject that they belong. I want to apply Graph2Vec and then use the embeddings of each document to train a text classifier.

I am using Karate Club's implementation of Graph2Vec:
https://karateclub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/karateclub/graph_embedding/graph2vec.html#Graph2Vec.fit

After reading their code it seems that the input of the model should be a list of NetworkX graphs and it outputs the embedding of each graph as a list in the same order as the graphs in the input list.

I have already implemented this function `document_to_graph()` that converts a text document to a graph. Here is my code:

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

document_folders = glob.glob("dataset")
graphs = []
X = []
y = []

for folder in document_folders:
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.txt')):
        graph = document_to_graph(file)
        graphs.append(graph)
        document_class = folder
        y.append(document_class)


# Train the Graph2Vec model
graph2vec_model = Graph2Vec()
graph2vec_model.fit(graphs)
graph_embeddings = graph2vec_model.get_embedding()


X = graph_embeddings
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=label_encoder.classes_)

print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
print(report)
```

My problem is that I have thousands of documents, so memory fills up as the graph list gets bigger and even if I test it for a smaller dataset it gives a pretty low accuracy.

What could be the problem here? Is my approach correct? Are there any other alternative Graph2Vec implementations to use besides Karate Club's?